# Load second page after the first finished loading

Tags: php, html

I have two pages `connect.php` and `disconnect.php`

I want to run `connect.php` to get connected then after i make sure `connect.php` was fully loaded i run some PHP code then i run the second page `disconnect.php` to disconnect.

```
// Run connect.php

if connect.php fully loaded{
  // Some PHP Code
  // Run disconnect.php
}
```

UPDATE : Maybe i gave too much details .. anyway my question is very simple : i have two pages `1.php` and `2.php` i want to call and execute both from main.php but not at the same time which means i want to execute `1.php` first then after it fully finished executing i pass to execute the second page `2.php` .. i used include ('`1.php`');  include ('`2.php`');  but both pages have automatic POST action so when i start main.php i get redirected to the post page .. i hope its clear now

Comment: By fully loaded, what does that mean? That your connection is going or that you successfully included the page?

Comment: PHP executes top to bottom.  disconnect.php won't run until connect.php has completed.

Comment: It sounds like you are needing a `true`/`false` indicator on your `connect.php` in order to determine if you should run your `disconnect.php` file, but it's hard to tell by the way you've worded your question.

Comment: Yes Rasclatt  exactly i want to know if connect.php was loaded (so i'm going to be sure i'm connected) successfully  then i run my code and disconnect by running disconnect.php

Comment: What do you exactly do in **connect.php** and **disconnect.php** ? You want to call both pages from another (eg.: main.php) page without redirection? What is supposed to do that `some PHP code` between connection and disconnection? The code you posted is supposed to be a javascript or PHP? And finally, by saying **`run page`** you mean you want to get it over ajax, include, or what? You cannot just throw a bunch of words, with code that do not match any of your tags, and expect to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Maybe i gave too much details .. anyway my question is very simple : i have two pages 1.php and 2.php i want to call and execute both from main.php but not at the same time which means i want to execute 1.php first then after it fully finished executing i pass to execute the second page 2.php .. i used include ('1.php');  include ('2.php');  but both pages have automatic POST action so when i start main.php i get redirected to the post page .. i hope its clear now

Comment: You wrote the same thing again replacing *run* to *execute* :) ... Simply : what are you doing within all these pages? What do you run/execute?

Comment: phillip100 : )  it doesn't matter what's the pages do, the most important is to not run both pages at the same time .. once page1.php complete execution execute second page pag2.php .. that's what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You could do some sort of ajax call and on success load the other page.

As an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"connect.php"
    data: "",
    success: function() {
      // include 'disconnect.php' here
    }
  });

});
```

However. If you're using PHP and not JavaScript/jQuery you don't need to worry about it.

PHP runs from the top of the file to the bottom.

You can literally have:

```
include 'connect.php';
//code here for connect.php
include 'disconnect.php';
```

Comment: I tried to use include ('connect.php'); but both pages has post form so i got redirected to other page and i lost original page. i tried also use <iframe> but both pages loaded same time